# Eclipse EMF adding structured text editor page is it possible?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf

have a Eclipse EMF editor which extends MultiPageEditorPart. This editor class is generated via Eclipse EMF. I did not add new codes or anything to this generated editor.

I want to add Structured Text editor page for .xml files.
I tried to add the following code into createPages() function:

```java
try {
    StructuredTextEditor sourceEditor = new StructuredTextEditor();
    int index = addPage(sourceEditor,getEditorInput());
    setPageText(index, "Source");
} catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But ctrl + z and ctrl + c don't work when i try this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the UNDO/REDO/etc. global action handlers to the corresponding actions in the `sourceEditor` instance when your editor part is activated, just like in `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicTextEditorActionContributor#doSetActiveEditor(IEditorPart)`, otherwise the key mapping won't know what's supposed to be run when your editor is active.